# Remove the rest of the string right after space

Tags: c#

I am getting string like this:

```
foreach (DataRow dt in dt_power_conv.Rows) {
    _powerConv.leit_conv.Add(dt["leit_"].ToString();
}
```

It's adding "ABB for the first time". I need to get "ABB",the rest should be removed. I have tried the following, but it does not change anything:

```
foreach (DataRow dt in dt_power_conv.Rows) {
    _powerConv.leit_conv.Add(dt["leit_"].ToString().Substring(0,(dt["leit_"].ToString()).LastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
}
```

Comment: You need to get the first 3 characters, the first word until a space or any other particular condition?

Comment: Can you provide example data for the leit_ column?

Comment: @EzequielLópez yes ,everything before the first space

Comment: @EzequielLópez "ABB for the first time"

Comment: "but it does not change anything:" that should not be true. You should get `ABB for the first ` as returning string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to get everything from a string before the first space? Your question is not very clear. But if so I would suggest:

```
string str = "ABB for the first time";
string str2 = str.Split(' ').First();
```

Answer (score 4):

One way with `String.IndexOf` and `Remove`:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt_power_conv.Rows) {
    string leit = row.Field<string>("leit_");
    int spaceIndex = leit.IndexOf(' ');
    leit = spaceIndex == -1 ? leit : leit.Remove(spaceIndex);
    _powerConv.leit_conv.Add(leit);
}
```

If the string is not long you could also use `Split` and `Enumerable.First` which is easier to read:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt_power_conv.Rows) {
    string leit = row.Field<string>("leit_");
    leit = leit.Split().First();
    _powerConv.leit_conv.Add(leit);
}
```

Note that `String.Split` without arguments also splits by tabs or new-line characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "ABB for the first time";
var abb = text.Split(' ').First();
```

Maybe not the most efficient, but easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Remove()` with `IndexOf()`:

```
foreach (DataRow dt in dt_power_conv.Rows) {

    string valueToAdd = dt["leit_"].ToString();

    int firstSpacePosition = valueToAdd.IndexOf(" ");

    if (firstSpacePosition >= 0)
        valueToAdd = valueToAdd.Remove(firstSpacePosition);

    _powerConv.leit_conv.Add(valueToAdd);
}
```

Edited to not repeat the IndexOf() function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you choose to use `LastIndexOf`, because as it says it gives you the **last index**. You need only a slight change to make your code work. Use the [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It:

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance.

and if you don't want to include the space into your string drop the `+1`

```
_powerConv.leit_conv.Add(
              dt["leit_"].ToString().Substring(0,(dt["leit_"].ToString()).IndexOf(" ")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here an example what you need:

```
  using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "Hellou1 Hellou2";
            int index = text.LastIndexOf(' ');
            text = text.Substring(0, index);
            Console.WriteLine(text);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: although I did not vote down, I can imagine why... `LastIndexOf` is the same method as OP uses. So this solution will only lead to the same problem as OP has posted